# Why did the Cloud Native Computing Foundation pick Prometheus over Graphite?

Tags: cloud, graphite, network-monitoring, prometheus

The Cloud Native Computing Foundation recently chose Prometheus over the more commonly known Graphite as their open source monitoring system incubation project. I was curious if anyone knew why they selected Prometheus over the more well-established monitoring tool Graphite and what makes it so much more compelling

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, graphite is not a monitor tool in the sense that it will not collect data for you. It is only used to store and display the graphs.

[From the graphite documentation](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html):

> What Graphite does not do is collect data for you, however there are some tools out there that know how to send data to graphite.

Prometheus also collects this data.